# Crystal Reports - crdb_adoplus.pdb not loaded

Tags: crystal-reports

My windows form application in Visual Studio 2019 compiles without any errors in the IDE; however when the program runs in the IDE and encounters any crystal reports call it crashes with the error:- crdb_adoplus.pdb not loaded.

I have looked at the solutions on Google and here none could resolve this error.

I am hoping someone here may have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error but, this is just a problem with error reporting.  Look a little closing and you may be able to find the root error.  I write to a log file in a try/catch and get the error first before this pops.